# How to set the Environment path variable ignoring the current user's path variable

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

I'm currently having an issue we're I'm trying to update the system path variable via powershell using the tutorial found in this link (http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/07/23/use-powershell-to-modify-your-environmental-path.aspx), but unfortunately, it'll sometimes not do anything due to the fact that the value is already in the current user's path. Is there some way to ignore the current user's path and only set the system one?

```
$AddedFolder = 'C:\Directory'

$OldPath=(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).Path

IF ($ENV:PATH | Select-String -SimpleMatch $AddedFolder)
{
    Return ‘Folder already within $ENV:PATH'
}

$NewPath=$OldPath.Trim(";")+’;’+$AddedFolder

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH –Value $NewPath
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `$OldPath` instead of `$env:Path` then. I'd also recommend splitting the value at semicolons and checking if `$AddedFolder` is contained in that array, otherwise you might get false positives if a subfolder is already listed in the PATH.

```
if ($OldPath.Split(';') -contains $AddedFolder) {
    Return 'Folder already within $ENV:PATH'
}
```